# Randomly Rotate Characters for Each H3 Span Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I have h3 elements in which each letter is in it's own span. This is because my chosen font is a balloon font and I want to give the impression they are different coloured balloons to make up my titel, no colour will be seen next to another and they will be randomly chosen on page load via looping through them all via my code below.

```
var defaultColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'],
    availColors = [],
    randomColor = '';

$('h3 span').each(function () {
    if (availColors.length == 0)
        availColors = defaultColors.slice(0);

    randomColor = availColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * availColors.length)];
    availColors = $.grep(availColors, function (value) {
        return value != randomColor;
    });
    $(this).css('color', randomColor);
});
```

I would like to add a further element of realism by rotating each character 30° clockwise or anti-clockwise, as if they are floating.

Have a look how the live view currently looks here: http://rafflebananza.com/new-website/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$(this).css('color', randomColor);
```

to

```
var degree = Math.random() > 0.5 ? '30' : '-30';

$(this).css({
    color               : randomColor,
    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform'    : 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform'     : 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform'      : 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    transform           : 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    zoom                : 1,
    display             : 'inline-block'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @adeneo however I believe I've done what you have suggested with no effect. I've updated the live view to see my edits.

Comment: @user3670469 - My bad, you can't rotate inline spans without setting them to inline-block

Comment: Thank you very much @adeneo I'm saving this question so I can +1 your answer as I don't yet have enough ratings to rate your answer sorry but be sure I am very grateful! :)

Comment: Just to note, got enough rep to +1 and I've just done so :) @adeneo